# Can I assign a reference to a constructor in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

My use case is in constructing a `WidgetApp` in flutter:

```
new WidgetsApp(
  pageRouteBuilder: <Contructor for MaterialPageRoute here>,
  ...
);
```

Instead of referencing the constructor, I'm just wrapping it in a function:

```
PageRoute pageRouteBuilder(RouteSettings settings, WidgetBuilder builder) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(settings: settings, builder: builder);
}
```

And then referencing that function later:

```
new WidgetsApp(
  pageRouteBuilder: pageRoutebuilder,
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be possible at some point in the history of Dart (like spread operator).
It is currently not possible though, but the feature may come back at some point.

In the meantime, you can use refactoring options for them to generate some of the boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor tear-off are not supported in Dart (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/10659)

But even if it was supported, your code cannot really use it. `MaterialPageRoute` takes `settings` and `builder` as named parameters but `PageRouteFactory` takes 2 positionals parameters. So it wouldn't match.

You can write it like:

```dart
  new WidgetsApp(
    pageRouteBuilder: (settings, builder) => MaterialPageRoute(settings: settings, builder: builder),
  );
```

The automatic inference, allows you to omit the type in the parameter of the closure.